# FileSystemCardStore shows undefined when imported from composer-common

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

What I did

```
const FileSystemCardStore = require('composer-common').FileSystemCardStore;
console.log('------>',FileSystemCardStore);
```

What I get is

> ------> undefined

I don't know if the API from the hyperledger community is wrong, cuz I don't see any FileSystemCardStore class in composer-common folder imported in node-modules.

My package.json says composer-common : "^0.19.0"

What is the problem ? and what I am doing wrong.

My Motive is to create a New Card for new Identity.

Answer (score 0):

corrected answer:

you need to use the following classes in your code ; `FileSystemCardStore` is not available in the current Composer release, like it was previously in a 0.16.x release.

A full example is shown here (it uses an in-memory card example, but the same principle applies to file-based cards)

https://github.com/hyperledger/composer-sample-networks/blob/master/packages/perishable-network/test/perishable.js

Note that you should ideally be using the latest Composer release -> see [here](https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/releases) to build your apps.